# How to install brother mfc-J615w printer wirelessly on ubuntu14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing

I am trying to use my Brother MFC-J615W wireless printer in Ubuntu 14.04.  I have installed the driver available from Brother (http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj615w_all&os=128) but it appears to only allow USB mode. It also does not seem to include the scan and fax options.

Comment: I notice there are separate drivers for scanning and faxing below the one that you downloaded.